# replacing multiple string value in timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns and I would like to replace the string 'X' and 'NULL' string with empty. I am not sure how to do multiple replacements in a timestamp column, your inputs, please.

data:

```
    sv     exp
    kdeh   2012-04-07T00:00:00Z
    hef    X
    jfrro  NULL
    jdz    X
    jfej   2011-04-07T00:00:00Z
```

Expected output:

```
        sv     exp
        kdeh   2012-04-07
        hef    
        jfrro  
        jdz    
        jfej   2011-04-07
```

My query which replaces only the NULL string with an empty row.

```
cast("sv" as integer) AS sv, 
to_localdate('yyyy-MM-dd', substring(replace("exp", 'NULL', ''), 0, 10)) as exp
from x_table
```

Comment: What are the replacement values for `X` and `NULL`?

Comment: I wanted to replace X and NULL with an empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try a basic update to replace string literal `X` and `NULL` values with SQL NULL:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET exp = NULL
WHERE exp IN ('X', 'NULL');
```

As a select you might try:

```
SELECT
    sv,
    CASE WHEN exp NOT IN ('X', 'NULL') THEN exp END AS exp
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I do not want to update the existing table. I want it to be included in the cast statement because I am creating a new view that will have to replace these values with empty.

Comment: Since I said i am trying to create a new view, check the format of the date I have in the updated table. Without the substring replace, it just gives me a date with TZ included. Sorry for not being clear before.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `case` expression?

```
(case when regexp_like(exp, '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$' then exp
      else <alternate value>
 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to_localdate('yyyy-MM-dd', substring(replace(replace("exp", 'NULL', ''),'X','') 0, 10)) as exp
from "x_table";
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post.